# Refresh Viewpager from within the DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, reload, drawerlayout

**Context:**
I have a drawerLayout that contains a list of cities that I get from Realm. The ViewPager is already displaying that list. You can delete a city directly from the DrawerLayout

**Problem:** When I delete a city from the DrawerLayout, I call mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged, the viewPager is not reloaded. Since the drawerLayout is displayed over the ViewPager, there is no reload when you close it and the ViewPager / Realm  returns a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 4 > 4` when I navigate back in it.

Do you have any clue on how I could solve that?

For information purpose, here is how it works:
**In the BaseActivity, that contains the DrawerLayout **

```
mCityListAdapter = new CityListAdapter(getBaseContext(), RealmHelper.getStoredCities(), new CityListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    }, new CityListAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(final int position) {
            final CharSequence[] items = {getString(R.string.action_delete_city)};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    RealmHelper.removeCity(RealmHelper.getStoredCities().get(position));
                    mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.delete_city_label));
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

**In the activity that contains the viewPager**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, mFrameLayout);

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

        mAdapter = new FragmentStatePageSupportAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), RealmHelper.getStoredCities().size(), this, RealmHelper.getStoredCities());
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

    }
```

**Edit**

I did override getItemPosition and it's called. So not the issue.

```
The @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Log.v("results", "called getitempostion");
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Comment: calling notifyDataSetChanged() on viewPager doesnt recreate your fragments, so you have to tell your fragment to refresh their data.

So you can use LocalBroadCastManager to tell your fragment to refresh the data.

Comment: Sounds a nice solution. So I put the LocalBroadcast in place, it works fine, but how would you force them to recreate? By instanciating the ViewPager again? Thanks

Comment: well i had the same problem but i never got viewPager to force recreate the fragments.

Comment: Maybe the problem is a more realm-related issue. I investigate.

Comment: I think I'm facing a known-bug https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/875

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? We had a race condition earlier that would manifest as this. The latest version is 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notify the data set only when a change actually occurs, like so

```
mRealmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Object element) {
        mCityListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

RealmHelper.getStoredCities().addChangeListener(mRealmChangeListener);
```

And

```
mCityListAdapter = new CityListAdapter(getBaseContext(), RealmHelper.getStoredCities(), new CityListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
       ...
    }
}, new CityListAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(final int position) {
        ...
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                RealmHelper.removeCity(RealmHelper.getStoredCities().get(position));
                ////mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); // remove this
            }
        });
        ...
    }
});
```

EDIT: okay, I guess in that case you should go the longer route:

```
mRealmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Object element) {
        mCityListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

RealmResults<City> listenerSet;
Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    listenerSet = realm.where(City.class).findAll();
    listenerSet.addChangeListener(mRealmChangeListener);
}
```

Or something of this sort.

Comment: Thanks for being around. Is it an issue if my ViewPager doesn't use a RealmAdapter but a classical one?

Comment: You don't need a `RealmAdapter`, but you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` in a `RealmChangeListener` instead of directly after the transaction.

Comment: Fine, I'm testing your answer :)

Comment: For some reason, and after having put a log to check, the onChange is not called when deleting my city T-T
I'm close